# Create facebook like menu

Tags: java, android

I want to open a menu of options similar to that of Facebook. I did a search but I did not find anything ...[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be needing to use `Bottom Sheets` for that :

**I - Make a bottomsheet.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="300dp"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="16dp"
   app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

   <!-- add your content here -->
</LinearLayout>
```

**II- now in your main activity implement it in a way it is a direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout`**

```
<include layout="@layout/bottomsheet" />
```

**III- For the JAVA code use the following:**

```
inearLayout bottomSheetViewgroup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior =  BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetViewgroup);
```

**To control your bottom sheet (hiding, expanding, dragging, collapsing):**

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

**PS- you can handle this by :**

> STATE_EXPANDED: To completely expand the bottom sheet.
>
> STATE_HIDE: To completely hide the bottom sheet.
>
> STATE_COLLAPSED: To set the bottom sheet height with the value set on the peekHeight attribute.